# Manage ssh keys within Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, ssh-keys

How do I clean up my ssh keys for my Virtual Servers. I have defined a number of keys but want to delete all of them and start a fresh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I connected to bluemix via the openstack client (installed on my workstation) and was able to delete the ssh keys with the commands above

Answer (score 0):

I guess right now your only option to delete them is through an OpenStack client on the command line. See [here](https://new-console.eu-gb.bluemix.net/docs/virtualmachines/vm_manage_sshkeys.html#vm_delete_ssh_key_cli) for details and on where to obtain that client.

List available ssh keys:

```
openstack keypair list
```

Delete a specific ssh key:

```
openstack keypair delete myKey
```

Comment: @CostaLochaitis then please mark the question as answered and upvote the answer